# Python 3 Concat Single Byte with String Bytes

Tags: python, byte

I need to concat a single byte with the bytes I get from a parameter string.

```
byte_command = 0x01
socket.send(byte_command + bytes(message, 'UTF-8'))
```

but I get this error:

```
socket.send(byte_command + bytes(message, 'UTF-8'))
TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

I assume this happens because I am using the string concat operator - how do I resolve that?

Comment: `byte_command = 0x01`, it is an int, if you want the `bytes` representation, use `byte_command  = b"\x01"`.

Comment: @CristiFati still does not work

Comment: The proximal cause of you error is passing an invalid argument to `bytes()`...If message is a string, then you need `message.encode()`... But is this really Python 3?

Comment: Nevermind I accidentally used python 2 -,-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, I get that you are running *Python2* (works in *Python3*). Assuming that *message* is a string:

- *Python **3*** ([[Python 3.Docs]: class bytes([source[, encoding[, errors]]])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes)):

  ```py
  byte_command = b"\x01"
  sock.send(byte_command + bytes(message, 'UTF-8'))
  ```
- *Python **2*** (where *bytes* and *str* are the same):

  ```py
  byte_command = "\x01"
  sock.send(byte_command + message)
  ```

I also renamed the *socket* to *sock* so it doesn't clash with the *socket* module itself.
As everyone suggested, it's recommended / common to do the transformation using `message.encode("utf8")` (in *Python 3* the argument is not even necessary, as *utf8* is the default encoding).

More on the differences (although question is in different area): [[SO]: Passing utf-16 string to a Windows function (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59521873/4788546).

Comment: Yes message is a string. But strangely I get for message="AUTH" I get:
01 65 85 84 72 16 and not 01 41 55 54 48 as I would expect it

Comment: Apperently the bytes I am sending have to be in hex representation - how would I do that?

Comment: I see, the 2nd value list is the hex representation of the ones in the 1st one. The bytes that you're sending? Meaning `message`? you should edit the question, and add the message as it is and how it should be (althought that would be a different question).

Comment: I created a new question as you advised: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48915590/python-3-convert-string-to-hex-bytes

Answer (score 0):

From that error message, it looks like you are using python2, not python3.  In python2, bytes is just an alias for str, and str only takes one argument.

To make something that works in python2 and python3, use str.encode rather than bytes:

```
byte_command = b'0x01'
socket.send(byte_command + message.encode('UTF-8'))
```