# Passing utf-16 string to a Windows function

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, ctypes, pywin32

I have a Windows dll called some.dll with the following function:

```
void some_func(TCHAR* input_string)
{
...
}
```

some_func expects a pointer to utf-16 encoded string.

Running this python code:

```
from ctypes import *

some_string = "disco duck"
param_to_some_func = c_wchar_p(some_string.encode('utf-16'))  #  here exception!

some_dll = ctypes.WinDLL(some.dll)
some_dll.some_func(param_to_some_func)
```

fails with exception **"unicode string or integer address expected instead of bytes instance**"

The documentation for ctypes and ctypes.wintypes is very thin, and I have not found a way to convert a python string to a Windows wide char and pass it to a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [[Python 3.Docs]: Built-in Types - Text Sequence Type - str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) (**emphasis** is mine):

> Textual data in Python is handled with [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) objects, or *strings*. Strings are **immutable [sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq) of Unicode code points**.

On *Win* they are *UTF16* encoded.

So, the correspondence between *CTypes* and *Python* (also visible by checking the **differences** between):

- [[Python **3**.Docs]: ctypes - Fundamental data types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types)
- [[Python **2**.Docs]: ctypes - Fundamental data types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types)

> ```
> ╔═══════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╗
> ║    CTypes     ║   Python 3   ║   Python 2   ║
> ╠═══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╣
> ║   c_char_p    ║    bytes     ║     str      ║
> ║   c_wchar_p   ║     str      ║   unicode    ║
> ╚═══════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╝
> ```

Example:

- *Python **3***:

  > ```py
  > >>> import ctypes as cts
  > >>> import sys
  > >>>
  > >>> sys.version
  > '3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]'
  > >>>
  > >>> text_ascii = b"Dummy"
  > >>> text_unicode = "Dummy"
  > >>>
  > >>> cts.c_char_p(text_ascii)
  > c_char_p(2563882450144)
  > >>>
  > >>> cts.c_wchar_p(text_ascii)
  > Traceback (most recent call last):
  >   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  > TypeError: unicode string or integer address expected instead of bytes instance
  > >>>
  > >>> cts.c_char_p(text_unicode)
  > Traceback (most recent call last):
  >   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  > TypeError: bytes or integer address expected instead of str instance
  > >>>
  > >>> cts.c_wchar_p(text_unicode)
  > c_wchar_p(2563878400656)
  > ```
- *Python **2*** (note that *str* <=> *unicode* conversions are performed automatically):

  > ```
  > >>> import ctypes as cts
  > >>> import sys
  > >>>
  > >>> sys.version
  > '2.7.17 (v2.7.17:c2f86d86e6, Oct 19 2019, 21:01:17) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]'
  > >>>
  > >>> text_ascii = "Dummy"
  > >>> text_unicode = u"Dummy"
  > >>>
  > >>> cts.c_char_p(text_ascii)
  > c_char_p('Dummy')
  > >>>
  > >>> cts.c_wchar_p(text_ascii)
  > c_wchar_p(u'Dummy')
  > >>>
  > >>> cts.c_char_p(text_unicode)
  > c_char_p('Dummy')
  > >>>
  > >>> cts.c_wchar_p(text_unicode)
  > c_wchar_p(u'Dummy')
  > ```

Back to your situation:

> ```
> >>> import ctypes as cts
> >>>
> >>> some_string = "disco duck"
> >>>
> >>> enc_utf16 = some_string.encode("utf16")
> >>> enc_utf16
> b'\xff\xfed\x00i\x00s\x00c\x00o\x00 \x00d\x00u\x00c\x00k\x00'
> >>>
> >>> type(some_string), type(enc_utf16)
> (<class 'str'>, <class 'bytes'>)
> >>>
> >>> cts.c_wchar_p(some_string)  # This is the right way
> c_wchar_p(2508534214928)
> >>>
> >>> cts.c_wchar_p(enc_utf16)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> TypeError: unicode string or integer address expected instead of bytes instance
> ```

As a side note, *TCHAR* varies (it's a *typedef*) on *_UNICODE* (not) being defined. Check [[MS.Learn]: Generic-Text Mappings in tchar.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/text/generic-text-mappings-in-tchar-h) for more details. So, depending on the *C* code compilation flags, the *Python* code might also need adjustments.

You could also check:

- [[SO]: Python 3 Concat Single Byte with String Bytes (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48911970/4788546).
- [[SO]: bytes.decode() in Python2 and Python3 (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57464901/4788546)
- [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546)