# There is a problem running create_string_buffer on python3 Enviroments

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

This is my sample Python 3 code.

```
from ctypes import create_string_buffer
import struct
...

# self.payload is None / max is integer
self.payload = create_string_buffer(max)

# self.payload is ctypes.c_char_Array_3
struct.pack_into(str(max) + "s", self.payload, 0, padding)
```

This is Error Code

```
struct.error: argument for 's' must be a bytes object
```

This sample code worked well in Python2 environment. However, the above error code was found during the conversion process to python3.

So, I forced conversion of self.payload to bytes(self.payload.raw) type results in the following Error Code.

```
TypeError: argumnet must be read-write bytes-like object, not bytes
```

How do we fix these errors and run them in a python3 environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing [[Python 3.Docs]: struct - Interpret strings as packed binary data](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#module-struct).

Things have changed between *Python 2* and *Python 3* regarding strings. Check [[SO]: Passing utf-16 string to a Windows function (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59520331/passing-utf-16-string-to-a-windows-function/59521873#59521873) for more details.

Although it's only guessable (as the question lacks relevant portions of the code (it's poorly written)), the culprit is *payload*, because that's the argument that corresponds to the "****s***" format (and it's not at all related to *self.payload*). So, the line should actually be:

```py
struct.pack_into(str(length) + "s", self.payload, 0, padding.encode())
```

Also, use another name for *max* (*e.g.* *length*), as you're shadowing the built-in function.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't pay attention to the fourth one.

And I also changed variable max .