# Calling a C function with a char* argument through python ctypes difference python2 and python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ctypes

I am converting a file from python2 to python3 that calls a C function using the `ctypes` module.
The below minimal example works in python2, however raises the following error in python3 (3.11)

OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x00000000000094E0

```c
// mydll.c
#include <stdio.h>

void myfunc(char* c, int i, char* c2) {
    printf("Hello World");
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

```py
# foo.py
import ctypes
import sys

PY3 = sys.version_info.major == 3

if PY3:
    clibrary = ctypes.WinDLL("mydll.dll", winmode=1)
else:
    clibrary = ctypes.WinDLL("mydll.dll")

prototype = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_char_p)

c1 = (ctypes.c_char * 512)()
i = ctypes.c_int(0)
c2 = (ctypes.c_char * (600 * 8))()
func = prototype(("myfunc", clibrary))


func(c1, i, c2)
```

I think this has something to do with unicode vs bytes representation of strings between python versions. From what I gather this looks like dereferencing a null pointer or something of that nature. I've tried using `ctypes.create_string_buffer()` but encounter the same error.

I expect the same code to work in both python2 and python3. What is causing the python3 error?

Comment: Just checking — is it calling `func` that raises the error, or is it the code that sets up the arg values?

Comment: Hi, the error occurs when calling `func`. I've also tried calling it from the library directly as in `clibrary.myfunc(c1, i, c2)` but encounter the same issue.

Comment: Note that `WinDLL` is used for 32-bit DLLs with `__stdcall` calling convention.  `CDLL` is normally what you need for default `__cdecl` calling convention.  On 64-bit it doesn't matter as there is only one calling convention.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the tip I was not sure what the difference is between the two. Is it best practice to use CDLL then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- According to [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - Loading shared libraries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#loading-shared-libraries) (**emphasis** is mine):

  > The *winmode* parameter is used on Windows to specify how the library is loaded (since *mode* is ignored). **It takes any value that is valid for the Win32 API `LoadLibraryEx` flags parameter**. When omitted, the default is to use the flags that result in the most secure DLL load to avoiding issues such as DLL hijacking. Passing the full path to the DLL is the safest way to ensure the correct library and dependencies are loaded.
- Then from [[MS.Learn]: LoadLibraryExA function (libloaderapi.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexa) (*DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES* - *0x00000001*) (***emphasis*** still mine):

  > **Note**  ***Do not use this value; it is provided only for backward compatibility***. If you are planning to access only data or resources in the DLL, use **LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE_EXCLUSIVE** or **LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE** or both. Otherwise, load the library as a DLL or executable module using the **LoadLibrary** function.

So, get rid of *winmode* (or set it to a supported value), and you should be fine.

Your example (a bit tweaked):

*dll00.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#if defined(_WIN32)
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API
#endif


#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

DLL00_EXPORT_API void func(char *pc0, int i, char *pc1);

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif


void func(char *pc0, int i, char *pc1)
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as cts
import sys


DLL_NAME = "./dll00.{:s}".format("dll" if sys.platform[:3].lower() == "win" else "so")


def main(*argv):
    dll = cts.WinDLL(DLL_NAME)

    prototype = cts.WINFUNCTYPE(None, cts.c_char_p, cts.c_int, cts.c_char_p)
    c0 = (cts.c_char * 512)()
    i = 0
    c1 = (cts.c_char * (600 * 8))()
    func = prototype(("func", dll))

    func(c0, i, c1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> (py_pc064_03.11_test0) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q074867788]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 > nul
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
> dll00.c
>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /DDLL dll00.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll00.dll
> dll00.c
>    Creating library dll00.lib and object dll00.exp
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
> dll00.c
> dll00.dll
> dll00.exp
> dll00.lib
> dll00.obj
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_02.07.18_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
> Python 2.7.18 (v2.7.18:8d21aa21f2, Apr 20 2020, 13:25:05) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Hello World
>
> Done.
>
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.11_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
> Python 3.11.0rc1 (main, Aug  8 2022, 11:30:54) [MSC v.1932 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Hello World
>
> Done.
> ```

**Notes**:

- Although not the case here, check [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) for a common error encountered when working with *CTypes*
- There are differences between the 2 *Python* versions regarding strings ([[SO]: Passing utf-16 string to a Windows function (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59521873/4788546)), but those don't impact the current scenario, as you're not using any
- Check [[SO]: Can't import dll module in Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59333711/4788546) for a more comprehensive analysis on the topic

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your answer! I had reached the conclusion that the winmode was causing the issue but was not clear why that was the case. Appreciate your additional information to help me understand.