# ctypes structure parameter understanding problem

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I was testing my structure class using `ctypes` in Python. Reading `ctypes Document 3.12.0`,
there was only `_fields_`.

```
class Struct(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('Header', ct.c_short),
        ('Data_int', ct.c_int64),
        ('Data_string', ct.c_char)
               ]

test = Struct()
test.Header = 10
test.Data_int = 64
test.Data_string = 'bx'
```

```
>>> 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-9b3bbfd7aaa9> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 test.Header = 10
      3 test.Data_int = 64
----> 4 test.Data_string = 'bx'

TypeError: one character bytes, bytearray or integer expected
```

Why `_fields_` does not work but next one works? Next one is `_field_`.

```
class Struct(ct.Structure):
    _field_ = [
        ('Header', ct.c_short),
        ('Data_int', ct.c_int64),
        ('Data_string', ct.c_char)
               ]

test = Struct()
test.Header = 10
test.Data_int = 64
test.Data_string = 'bx'
```

```
>>>
```

Comment: [\[SO\]: Passing utf-16 string to a Windows function (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59521873/4788546).

Answer (score 1):

Well the actual attribute name is `_fields_`.`ct.c_char` ctype type equivalent to 1-character bytes object in python. So you need to assign one character byte object to `test.Data_string` to make your first snippet work.

```
import ctypes as ct

class Struct(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('Header', ct.c_short),
        ('Data_int', ct.c_int64),
        ('Data_string', ct.c_char)
               ]

test = Struct()
test.Header = 10
test.Data_int = 64
test.Data_string = b'b'
```

And regarding your second snippet `_field_` is not special. Python allows you dynamically assign attributes. So even if you delete `_field_` and try to assign the atrributes it won't raise any errors. However, when using `_field_`, you won't achieve the intended functionality.

```
import ctypes as ct


class Struct(ct.Structure):
    pass
test = Struct()
test.Header = 10
test.Data_int = 64
test.Data_string = b'b'
```

Comment: omg, that was, my huge mistake(?). Thank you for your sincere answer, sir.